# wordpress with 1.5 million posts

Tags: optimization

I wanted to transform my dictionaries into a WordPress website that has different dictionaries for different views. As you can imagine by now, the posts will mostly have just 2 words and a short sentence of the definition.

so The post body will mostly be this big:

```
home  / casa
a place when people love
```

I'm not sure how much space that post would occupy considering it will be linked to 1 category (no tags nothing else) and have an explanatory title like `casa translation`

The text files in total consist in about 100MB of space I'm guessing as WordPress posts they would occupy double that. So I have 1Gb of ram. Will this be enough according to you WP experts out there?

Any possible fine tuning/customization I could make?

Like fcgicache or some mysql cache because I'm thinking WP super cache would not be a good option for so many files.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274130/94498) answer might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 GB on virtual private server (VPS) should be enough, if you don't have a high traffic.

WP Cache could cause problems when number of posts is more than 30,000 due to limitations on file descriptors.

Main rules of tuning nginx, php and MySQL are the same as for high traffic site. You can read relevant [article in my blog](https://kagg.eu/en/10000-clients-second-wordpress/).